# Why does getElementsByTagName only grab every other element here?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

With this code using DomDocument:

```
<?php
$html = '<pre>one</pre><pre>two</pre><pre>three</pre><pre>four</pre>';

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$sub = $doc->getElementsByTagName("pre");
foreach($sub as $pre) {
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment(); 
    $fragment->appendXML(str_replace('&', '&amp;', '<p>& it\'s replaced</p>'));
    $pre->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $pre);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

I get this output:

```
<p>& it's replaced</p> 
<pre>two</pre>
<p>& it's replaced</p>
<pre>four</pre>
```

[**Working (or not) example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oiMIzT)

Can someone explain to me what is going on and why all the `pre` tags aren't being replaced?

Comment: Im not sure but if i had to guess its because its actually an HTML fragment and not a full document. Try wrapping them in `<html><body></body></html>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/ALYWEi

```
<?php
$html = '<pre>one</pre><pre>two</pre><pre>three</pre><pre>four</pre>';

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$sub = $doc->getElementsByTagName("pre");
$i = $sub->length - 1;
while ($i > -1) {
    $pre = $sub->item($i);
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment(); 
    $fragment->appendXML(str_replace('&', '&amp;', '<p>& it\'s replaced</p>'));


    $pre->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $pre);

    $i--;
} 

echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

I found the issue when I googled "DomDocument replacechild" without the quotes

see the first comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php particularly this:

> If you are trying to replace more than one node at once, you have to be careful about iterating over the DOMNodeList.  If the old node has a different name from the new node, it will be removed from the list once it has been replaced.  Use a regressive loop:

Comment: Thank you! And that's why if you replace a node with the same element type it works -> http://codepad.viper-7.com/HIvyyD

Comment: I think you have to work backwards through the list as the list gets shorter.

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with the direction:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $sub->length; $i++) {
    $pre = $sub->item($i);
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML(str_replace('&', '&amp;', '<p>& it\'s replaced</p>'));
    $pre->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $pre);
}
```

doesn't work but

```
for ($i = $sub->length -1; $i >=0; $i--) {
    $pre = $sub->item($i);
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML(str_replace('&', '&amp;', '<p>& it\'s replaced</p>'));
    $pre->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $pre);
}
```

works fine. There must be something like an internal counter, I reckon.

HTH Andreas

Comment: Sorry, haven't read the comment at the bottom of the other answer.